# React NPM Porlet deployed but it is not available in applications panel on Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I'm new to LifeRay development still learning the ropes so please bear with me.

I created only the shell of an npm react portlet using the blade cli template, I'm using LifeRay CE 7.0.4 GA5 with mySql database.

After doing a few tries getting the right dependencies i was able to deploy it. And i get this message back from the console:

04:20:26,149 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:252] Processing com.st.npm.react-1.0.0.jar
04:20:33,151 INFO  [fileinstall-C:/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga5/osgi/modules][BundleStartStopLogger:38] STOPPED com.st.npm.react_1.0.0 [520]
04:20:33,858 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 706ebb15-e5df-0018-1059-8ffb03af5e89][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.st.npm.react_1.0.0 [520]

And just to be safe i ran diag on the new bundle deployed in gogo shell and looks good, no errors showing up.

My problem is that i don't see it displayed under applications > sample category to add it to a page. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Here is my project:

https://github.com/JAlonsoHdz/NPM_React.git

Comment: What blade command did you use to create the template? Have you tried using these instructions: https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/npm-react-portlet-template

Comment: Try the blade command 'blade create -t npm-react-portlet -v 7.0 ReactTest'.